# fontsize does affect only part of the text

Tags: koma-script, fontsize

I use `scrbook`and want to set the font for some part of the text with `fontsize`. The effect is that the text in the normal font is in the normal font size and only special fonts are scaled by fontsize.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\KOMAoptions{ fontsize=11pt }

\usepackage{anyfontsize}

\begin{document}
    some normal text \\
    {
        \fontsize{4pt}{9.5pt}
%       \footnotesize
        Teile dieses Buches wurde  Programmen in Haskell erstellt. Der Text wurde 
        mit  {\LaTeX}, {Lua\LaTeX} and {\KOMAScript} gesetzt. 
    }
\end{document}
```

The result shows only the KOMAScript part is smaller: 
[image]

The fontsizes are selected for contrast and not what is ultimately used!

Comment: `\fontsize{4pt}{9.5pt}\selectfont`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`\fontsize{4pt}{9.5pt}` only sets up the internal parameters for the next font selection, it does not actually select a font, you need `\selectfont` to do that, also if you want the 9.5pt baseline to be used you need a blank line or `\par` before the closing `}` as the baseline at the end of the paragraph is used for the whole paragraph.