# Why does the linespacing apply only to the first line?

Tags: titles, fontsize, baseline

I am making my own title page(there are better ways), what I don't understand is for the line:

```
{\fontsize{18pt}{25pt}\selectfont FOooo\\COOoooo\\Fooooo}
```

Why only the first line respects the linespacing argument and not the second one.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{titling,geometry}

\geometry{left=1in,top=1in,right=1in,bottom=1in}

\title{Assignment}

\begin{document}
\vspace*{3cm}
\begin{center}
    \textbf{\fontsize{28pt}{6pt}\selectfont \thetitle}\\
    \vspace{2cm}
    {\fontsize{12pt}{4pt} \today}\\
    \vspace{2cm}
    {\fontsize{18pt}{25pt}\selectfont FOooo\\COOoooo\\Fooooo}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

I got the following output

[image: Output of the above MWE]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

[fontsize does affect only part of the text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/495094/fontsize-does-affect-only-part-of-the-text?rq=1)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{titling,geometry}

\geometry{left=1in,top=1in,right=1in,bottom=1in}

\title{Assignment}

\begin{document}
\vspace*{3cm}
\begin{center}
    \textbf{\fontsize{28pt}{6pt}\selectfont \thetitle}\\
    \vspace{2cm}
    {\fontsize{12pt}{4pt} \today}\\
    \vspace{2cm}
    {\fontsize{18pt}{25pt}\selectfont FOooo\\COOoooo\\Fooooo

    }
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\fontsize{28pt}{6pt}` ??? why specify 28pt font separated by baselines 6pt apart? that will make wildly inconsistent linespacing

Answer (score 3):

when you have

```
  \textbf{\fontsize{28pt}{6pt}\selectfont \thetitle}\\
   xxx
```

Then normally `\\`  will make a newline but not end the paragraph so the baseline setting will end at the `}` but the paragrah will end later and use the baseline setting at that point.

Somewhat unfortunately `center` implements `\\`  using `\par` so it does internally end the paragraph and so the 6pt!!! baseline is used for the first `\\`  but the second `\\`  is after the `}` so the baselineskip set before this code will be in effect.

You almost never want the second argument of `\selectfont` to be smaller than the first. Also it's usually better to use the named sizes to arrange consistent choices.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{titling,geometry}

\geometry{left=1in,top=1in,right=1in,bottom=1in}

\title{Assignment}

\begin{document}
\vspace*{3cm}
\begin{center}
    {\Huge\textbf{\thetitle}\par}

    \vspace{2cm}
    \today

    \vspace{2cm}
    {\Large\selectfont FOooo\par COOoooo\par Fooooo\par}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]